# How to change month descriptions on a DevExtreme Calendar?

Tags: .net-core, frontend, devexpress, devextreme

I'm using the Calendar and DateBox components from DevExtreme.
My current language is set to pt-BR.

As shown in the image, the months descriptions are like **"jan."** but I'd like it to be **"Jan"**.

[image]

Looking for some samples/demos on the internet ([example1](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DateBox/Formatting/AngularJS/Light/) or [example2](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Calendar/Overview/NetCore/Light/)), the description as "Jan" is the default behaviour.

The code I'm using (the simplest):

```
Html.DevExtreme().DateBox()
    .Type(DateBoxType.Date)
```

As a result of this, I'm trying to use DisplayFormat as "MMM/yyyy" and it makes the description like **"jan./2021"** and not **"Jan/2021"** as I'd like to.

Is there a way I can change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try with "MM/yyyy" instead of "MMM/yyyy", it should work